# Demonstrate that range of function is open

Tags: real-analysis

Given that $f=x^2-2$, how can it be shown the range of such a function is open on R.

I know that I must approach it by creating some ball with epsilon radius and showing another point from the range is contained in the ball. But, I am not sure how to formalize the proof. Can I use the fact that the function itself is continuous?

Comment: Is it really open?

Comment: $x^2-2$ is always $\ge 2$, and $-2$ is attained at $x=0$. So the range is $[-2,\infty)$, not open. (Every neighbourhood of $-2$ contains a point not in the range.)

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=x^2-2\;,\;\;f'(x)=2x\;,\;\;f''(0)=2>0\implies (0,-2)$$

is a minimal point of $\;f\;$ , and as this is a continuous, everywhere defined function, and $\;f(x)\xrightarrow[x\to\pm\infty]{}\infty\;$, then that is an absolute minimum point, and from here that

$$f(\Bbb R)=[-2,\infty)=\text{ a closed subset (in the usual topology) of}\;\Bbb R$$

So nop: the image of the function isn't open.

A more basic approach: $\;f(x)=x^2-2\;$ is an upwards vertical parabola and thus it has an absolute minimum at its vertex, which is $\;(0,-2)\;$ .